# Apache Alias Infinite Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, alias

I've been having a lot of trouble with setting up an Alias for my Virtualhost.

I have 2 different codebases that need to be on the same server, I have the admin app as well as the client app.

My virtual host is as follows :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/site/client"
    ServerName local.site.com

    Alias /admin/ E:/xampp/htdocs/site/admin/
</VirtualHost>
```

My folder structure is as follows :

```
site
  - admin
  - client
```

Everything works fine as far as the client goes, I can hit everything under the subdirectory.

The issue arises when I try to hit `local.site.com/admin`. It redirects the URL to `local.site.com/admin/index.php/index.php...` and so on (there is like 10 of them).

I also can not hit the `index.html` in the admin folder directly.

The result I expect is for all traffic to `/admin` to be directed to the admin folder.

I can not for the life of me figure out why the redirect is happening.

I do not have any .htaccess files in the folders for what its worth.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Take care to also specify a trailing slash `/` in the target path of the `Alias` command. This is documented. You should read the documentation of the modules you are using.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I do have the trailing slash. Just missed typing it in in the question, will edit the post. I have read the following documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) and various posts on here without any luck.

Comment: It should not result in an endless redirect if you did specify a trailing slash in both, source and target path inside the `Alias` directive. Can it be you are hitting a cache issue here? Try a "deep reload" in your browser or clear its cache. If the issue persists you have to 1. monitor the access log file and 2. check your browsers development console and examine the "network" tab in there to understand what is going on.

Comment: Wow, the hard reload works. Now I feel like an idiot :( I was restarting the server after every update and nothing was changing. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: All fine :-) Glad I could help. Have fun!